# Network traffic recording-playback system

Tags: wireshark, pcap, network-traffic, tcpreplay

I am using tcpreplay and I need to synchronize two or more machines replaying recorded network traffic.

Do You know how can I synchronize replaying pcap file on multiple hosts ?

Maybe there is a better way than using tcpreplay?

Thanks for answer.